# What is a metabolite?

Tags: biochemistry, metabolism

I am a mathematician and work on metabolic networks as networks. But I could not find a proper definition for a metabolite? Are they organic molecules? can a gene or a protein also be a metabolite?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metabolite

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Please take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site and [edit] your question accordingly. In particular, we expect you to demonstrate that you have done some research on your own and then, informed by what you have learned, ask any questions you still have (ideally with references to reliable sources). At a minimum please tell us where you looked and what you learned. Thanks! 

Comment: If you go by meaning that "organic"  means made in the organism by biological processes ,then in vitro metabolites are surely organic ,if the reactions are occurring in-vitro.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metabolism

Comment: Thank you, indeed I meant in general because in a paper I found it is an organic molecule, but from the below comment I found it depends on the context.

Comment: Why was this question closed? It seems to be relevant to biology and helpful to a general audience to investigate a solid definition of "metabolite".

Comment: yeah, I think many people who are not a biologist they might have these kinds of questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This definition of [Metabolism](https://www.britannica.com/science/metabolism) is similar to most I've seen in biology textbooks.

> Metabolism: the sum of the chemical reactions that take place within each cell of a living organism and that provide energy for vital processes and for synthesizing new organic material.

The broadest definition I would give for "metabolite" is any molecule that's part of or a product of a metabolic reaction. They are molecules, but not necessarily organic molecules (in the traditional sense). For example, any metabolically active cell is going to constantly generate inorganic phosphate as a metabolite of ATP hydrolysis.

> can a gene or a protein also be a metabolite?

I suppose A protein could be considered a metabolite, but it would depend on the context. most people probably would not be talking about proteins when making reference to "metabolites" in general way. For example, an enzyme acting as a catalyst in a biochemical reaction would probably not be considered a metabolite of that specific reaction (since it's not chemically changed in the process). But in a metabolic model involving protein degradation, it would have to be included in some way. However, amino acids (the monomer building blocks of proteins), are often incorporated into metabolomic analyses, and could be considered important metabolites in many different cellular reactions.

A gene is not a metabolite by any reasonable definition. A gene is not a biological molecule, but a unit of hereditary information. One could argue that the nucleic acid molecules (DNA or RNA) encoding a gene sequence are metabolites, but as with proteins, it would really be context dependent. Also similar to proteins, the structural subunits of nucleic acid polymers (nucleosides and nucleotides) are often important metabolites involved in a great number of cellular functions.

Is all of that about as clear as mud?

Comment: Thank you MikeyC, now many things are more clear for me.